# Como obter os últimos dias do mês em PHP

Tags: php, data

Quero obter os últimos dias do mês atual. Esse é o código para a data de hoje:

```
$datee= date("d/m/Y");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Veja os [parâmetros de formatação existentes na função `date()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

O `t` é o que determina o último dia do mês.

```
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("2014-10-29")) . "\n";
echo date("Y-m-t") . "\n"; //data de hoje
echo date("t");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JBI2Ua). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qkilosdf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/GetSpecific.php).

Também existe uma função própria para isto chamada [`cal_days_in_month()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) mas a primeira forma é mais usada.

Existe ainda a possibilidade de pegar o primeiro dia do próximo mês e subtrair um dia da data mas também acho desnecessário.

Answer (score 6):

Outra opção é fazer:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('d'); // somente o dia
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $date->format('d/m'); //dia e mês
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $date->format('d/m/Y'); //dia mês e ano
```

**[Exemplo Ideone](http://ideone.com/6onLNL)**

Answer (score 2):

Dê uma olhada [neste projeto](https://github.com/sinergia/brasil), e encontrará algumas operações com data que precisar além de outras funcionalidades como máscaras, validações etc.

Exemplo para pegar o último dia do mês:

```
$minha_data = new DateBr();
$ultimo_dia_do_mes = $minha_data->lastOfMonth();
```

Comment: Justificando meu negativo: Usar uma biblioteca quando já se tem nativamente seria um desperdício de recurso.

Answer (score 1):

Tranquilo basta utilizar a classe date junto com a `strtotime`.

```
<?php

$P_Dia_Mes_Atual = date("Y-m-01 00:00:00:00");
$U_Dia_Mes_Atual = date("Y-m-t 00:00:00:00");

$P_Dia_Mes_Anterior = date("Y-m-01 00:00:00:00",strtotime("-1 month"));
$U_Dia_Mes_Anterior = date("Y-m-t 00:00:00:00",strtotime("-1 month"));

print $P_Dia_Mes_Atual;
print $U_Dia_Mes_Atual;

print $P_Dia_Mes_Anterior;
print $U_Dia_Mes_Anterior;
```

Answer (score 1):

Há uma função nativa no PHP que faz isso
`cal_days_in_month`. Como ela funciona
`cal_days_in_month(int $calendar, int $month, int $year): int`

Por exemplo se quiseres pegar o último dia de Fevereiro de dois anos distintos ficaria algo assim:

```php
echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,2,2020);
//Resultado 29

echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,2,2021);
//Resultado 28
```

a utilização do `CAL_GREGORIAN` é por causa do suporte até a versão 8 do PHP a apenas `CAL_GREGORIAN, CAL_JULIAN, CAL_JEWISH e CAL_FRENCH`.

Para mais informações consulte o

1. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.cal-days-in-month.php
2. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.cal-info.php