# Loop autoincrementando data

Tags: php

Como posso fazer um *auto increment* de data por mês e mostrando o ultimo dia do mes

Exemplo:

> 2017-01-31
>
> 2017-02-28
>
> 2017-03-31

```
$parcelas  = 12;
$data_inicial = 2017-01-31
for ($i = 1; $i <= $parcelas; $i++){        
    // abaixo o auto increment
    echo $data_inicial.........??????
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38633/91

Comment: Ok interessante o 't'.... mais i como fazer ele em sequencia

Comment: Tente algo assim dentro do seu `for`: `echo date('Y-m-t', strtotime("2017-" . ($i < 10 ? "0$i" : $i) . "-01")) . "\n";`

Answer (score 4):

Para pegar sempre as última data do mês use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) com [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php):

> `date('t', mktime());`

Gerar parcelas pelo último dia do mês de acordo com a informação do ano:

```
function gerar_parcelas($y = 2017) 
{
    $parc = array();        
    for($i = 1; $i < 13;$i++){
        $parc[] = date('Y-m-t', mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,(int)$y));
    }
    return $parc;
}

var_dump(gerar_parcelas(2017));
```

[***Exemplo***](http://ideone.com/WSvMQu)

---

Nesse outro código é gerado como se fosse *parcelas de pagamento*, ou seja, se informou **13/12/2005** e a quantidade de parcelas o algoritmo gerar a partir dessa data só alterando o mês e ano se for pra o próximo. Esse código também se encaixa a sua duvida se for informado a última data do mês com **12** parcelas.

Gerar parcelas por uma data:

```
<?php

function parcelas($data, $numero = 12)
{
    $parc = array();
    $parc[] = $data;
    list($ano, $mes, $dia) = explode("-", $data);
    for($i = 1; $i < $numero;$i++)
    {
        $mes++;
        if ((int)$mes == 13)
        {
            $ano++;
            $mes = 1;
        }
        $tira = $dia;
        while (!checkdate($mes, $tira, $ano))
        {
            $tira--;
        }
        $parc[] = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d", $ano, $mes, $tira);
    }
    return $parc;
}


$data = "2017-01-31";

var_dump(parcelas($data, 12));
```

[***Exemplo***](http://ideone.com/BN8vex)

<sup>Nesse segundo exemplo é gerado pela data então para funcionar igual está na pergunta sempre tem que passar o último dia do primeiro mês do ano, porque, esse código gera para qualquer dia do mês diferente do primeiro que pega o ano e gera as últimas data do mês daquele ano.</sup>

***Referencias:***

- [date](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)
- [mktime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php)
- [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.checkdate.php)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim

```
<?php
$parcelas = 12;
$data_inicial = '2017-01-31';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $parcelas; $i++){        
    echo $data_inicial."<br>";
    $d = new DateTime( $data_inicial );
    $d->modify( 'last day of next month' );
    $data_inicial = $d->format( 'Y-m-d' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Matar uma mosca com uma bala de canhão?! Pois bem, pensei em uma maneira bem simples de resolver seu problema que seria você usar [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php). Veja o código abaixo:

```
<?php    
function returnDates($parcelas, $ultima_data){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $parcelas; $i++){   
       $date = strtotime("+$i month", strtotime($ultima_data));
       echo date("Y-m-t", $date)."\n";
    } 
}

echo returnDates(20,"2007-02-12");
```

No exemplo acima eu chamo a função colocando o numero de parcelas e a data inicial.

Veja o [**exemplo** funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/JprwOi).

Comment: @fabio-henrique Depois tenta desta forma aqui e me fala o que acha! Abs.

Answer (score -1):

```
         $m=0; 
         for($i=1;$i <= $nparcelas; $i++){
            $a1 = new DateTime($data_inicial);
            $a2 = new DateInterval('P'.$m.'M');
            $a1->add($a2);
            $a1->format("Y-m-d") -> formatação datetime para inserir no banco
            $m++;
         }
```

Comment: você testou o código ? no teste que eu fiz a variavel `$m` não existe, alterando ela para `$i` tem um problema do mês 1 para 2 por ter apenas 28(ou 29) dias.

Comment: cria ela antes $m=0; e no fim do for $m++; assim o loop começa com o mês atual e tem o auto incremento de 1 a 1

Comment: Entendi, mas o problema de se perder das datas continua, execute seu código para ver o resultado.

Comment: eu uso ele.. ele vai auto incrementar na medida que você quiser que $m seja incremento seja ++ (de 1 em 1) ou $m = $m +2 ;  e por ae vai...

Comment: Quanto tiver tempo faz o teste simulando que está no dia 29, 30 ou 31. Nos demais dias funciona normalmente.

Comment: estranho aqui funcionou normal, gerei 3 parcelas a partir do dia 29/11 e ele gerou as 3 consecutivas normal.. não vejo o que pode estar fazendo essa perca da sequencia

Comment: Faz com 4 parcelas, ai vai cair no mês de fevereiro que tem 28 dias, e ele vai pular para o mês seguinte.

Comment: a sim, mais ai precisa tratar essas exceções dentro do for, pra toda a regra existe uma exceção, alem disso caso tenha essa necessidade de precisão talvez tenha interesse em tratar feriados e por ai vai....