# Mysql acima de 5mil linhas

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Bom pessoal estou a desenvolver um código só que me deparei com o seguinte problema, quando realizei teste de performance com 5mil linhas ele excedeu o limite de 30 seg... o que pode esta de errado?

```
$app->get('/receitagrafico/', function() use ($app) {
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
 $router = $app->router();

$datai = date("Y-m-01");
$dataf = date("Y-m-t");

    $stmt1 = getConn()->query("SELECT SUM(totalz + entrega - ajuste) AS valor_total_soma FROM movimento WHERE status!='C' AND data BETWEEN '{$datai}' AND '{$dataf}'");
        $onoff = ( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 ? true : false );
        $dados_produto = $stmt1->fetchObject();
        $total_atual = ( $onoff ? $dados_produto->valor_total_soma : 0 );

    $stmt1 = getConn()->query("SELECT SUM(totalz + entrega - ajuste) AS valor_total_soma FROM movimento WHERE status!='C' AND data BETWEEN '{$datai}' AND '{$dataf}'");
        $onoff = ( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 ? true : false );
        $dados_produto = $stmt1->fetchObject();
        $bugfix = ( $dados_produto->valor_total_soma == 0 ? 1 : $dados_produto->valor_total_soma );
        $total_passado = ( $onoff ? ($total_atual-$dados_produto->valor_total_soma)/$bugfix*100 : 0 );

$total_lanche = [];
$lanche_lengd = [];
    $stmt1 = getConn()->query("SELECT produtos,data FROM movimento WHERE status!='C' AND data BETWEEN '{$datai}' AND '{$dataf}'");
        $onoff = ( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 ? true : false );
        while($dados_produto = $stmt1->fetchObject()){
            if ($stmt1->rowCount() > 0) {
                $arr = explode(',', $dados_produto->produtos);
                $arrN_am = array();
                foreach($arr as $item){
                    $valor = explode(':', $item);
                    $arrN_am[][$valor[0]] = $valor[1];
                }
                foreach($arrN_am as $item => $id){
                    foreach($id as $item2 => $id2){
                        $id_produto = $item2;
                        $qtd = $id2;
                        if(is_double($id2)){
                            $qtd = 1;
                        }
                        $stmt3 = getConn()->query("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE hash={$item2}");
                        $resultado_lanche = $stmt3->fetchObject();
                        if (!isset($total_lanche[$resultado_lanche->nome])) {
                            $total_lanche[$resultado_lanche->nome] = $qtd;
                            $lanche_lengd[] = $resultado_lanche->nome;
                        }else{
                            $total_lanche[$resultado_lanche->nome] += $qtd;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($onoff){
            $tt3 = $lanche_lengd;
            $tt4 = [];
            foreach($total_lanche as $item => $id){
                $tt4['name'] = 'Abril';
                $tt4['data'][] = $id;
            }
        }else{
            $tt3 = 0;
            $tt4 = false;
        }

echo "[";
echoResponse(200, $total_atual);
echo ",";
echoResponse(200, $total_passado);
echo ",";
echoResponse(200, $tt3);
echo ",";
echoResponse(200, [$tt4]);
echo "]";

});
```

Retorno:

```
[53,0,["Torrada","Cachorro quente"],[{"name":"Abril","data":[4,1]}]]
```

1ªedição: pronto fiz as alterações nas variáveis, na db para DATE, e no código, não coloquei o date como index. Já fiz um teste com 5mil linhas nesse novo código e continua excedendo o tempo

estrutura do bd:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nova comparação... funcionou 5mil querys

```
        $stmt3 = getConn()->query("SELECT hash,nome FROM produto");
        $resultado_lanche = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $resultado_lanche = array_map('reset', $resultado_lanche);
        $resultado_lanche = array_map('reset', $resultado_lanche);

$total_lanche = [];
$lanche_lengd = [];
    $stmt1 = getConn()->query("SELECT produtos,data FROM movimento WHERE status!='C' AND data BETWEEN '{$datai}' AND '{$dataf}'");
        $onoff = ( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 ? true : false );
        while($dados_produto = $stmt1->fetchObject()){
            if ($stmt1->rowCount() > 0) {
                $arr = explode(',', $dados_produto->produtos);
                $arrN_am = array();
                foreach($arr as $item){
                    $valor = explode(':', $item);
                    $arrN_am[][$valor[0]] = $valor[1];
                }
                foreach($arrN_am as $item => $id){
                    foreach($id as $item2 => $id2){
                        $id_produto = $item2;
                        $qtd = $id2;
                        if(is_double($id2)){
                            $qtd = 1;
                        }

                        if (!isset($total_lanche[$resultado_lanche[$item2]])) {
                            $total_lanche[$resultado_lanche[$item2]] = $qtd;
                            $lanche_lengd[] = $resultado_lanche[$item2];
                        }else{
                            $total_lanche[$resultado_lanche[$item2]] += $qtd;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Execute suas queries com um `EXPLAIN` na frente (logo antes do `SELECT`) e poste os resultados aqui. Só assim será possível opinar com precisão. Provavelmente será necessário criar índices nas suas tabelas. Salvar as datas com o tipo adequado em vez de string deve ajudar também.

Comment: Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$totalz
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\loja\pHpServer-ADm\api\v1\index.php
Line: 4528

Comment: A gambiarra no armazenamento de data é o maior problema (talvez não seja o unico). Já tem o campo com formato de data por uma razão. Data se formata apenas na hora da exibição, não no banco. A primeira coisa a fazer é converter as colunas da tabela para Date ou DateTime.

Comment: blz vou ajusta esse campo data, mais algum problema critico ou alguma dica para reescrever?

Comment: Tenta isso primeiro, e veja o que mudou. Tou lendo o resto pra ver se tem mais coisa. Lembre que vai ter que arrumar o lado PHP para passar a data em AAAA-MM-DD no between

Comment: Tá fácil, basta converter o campo (sugestão: crie um campo datetime, e não mexa no original ainda, dê um UPDATE tabela SET camponovo = STR_TO_DATE.... campovelho) e depois mude `$id = "01/".$dfaxxx256.$dfa43;` para `$id = $dfa43.'-'.$dfaxxx256.'-01';`

Comment: Se você depois [edit] o post e formatar melhor a indentação do seu código, ajuda a ler também.

Comment: O select vai ficar mais ou menos assim: `WHERE data BETWEEN '$id' AND '$id2'`

Comment: Aliás, nem precisa de 2 variáveis. Pode por os dias no próprio select: `WHERE data BETWEEN '{$anomes-01}' AND '{$anomes-31}' ` - Poderia também usar `WHERE MONTH(data) = $mes AND YEAR(data) = $ano`, simplesmente, mas aí não aproveita índice. Cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Tem mais um cuidado - o MySQL aceita no between datas ilegais como 31 de janeiro, mas não valida na inserção. Melhor seria rever a lógica do 31, pegando o ultimo dia do mês com PHP - Tem resposta pra isso no site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38632/70

Comment: @Bacco ja atualizei com o máximo que consegui

Comment: Bom, agora com o código indentado melhor, dá pra ver que você está fazendo outra query dentro do loop da primeira. O problema dificilmente é no MySQL agora, e sim no seu loop. Precisa repensar essa lógica toda pra fazer duas queries apenas. Por exemplo, faz a primeira pra pegar os hashes todos, e depois faz outra pra pegar os produtos. Fora isso, em vez do SELECT *, você pode pegar apenas as colunas que realmente vai usar. Pra ser sincero, refazer o código pensando melhor dá menos trabalho do que tentar consertar essa lógica. Tem muita complicação.

Comment: Mesmo a primeira query, não entendi a razão  de fazer duas vezes. E tem tanto foreach dentro do outro que é até dificil acompanhar. Provavelmente não precisaria de tudo isso. Seria mais fácil se você explicasse a estrutura das tabelas, e o resultado que quer obter (com um exemplo do que deveria ser retornado), em vez de mostrar o modo que acha que vai resolver.

Comment: seguinte a primeira pega o total do mes atual, a segunda pega o total to mes passado, e faz a taxa de crescimento. a terceira query organiza tudo em nome/quantidade

Comment: @Bacco achei aqui... e a logica da terceira querry... agora como simplifico essa analise

Comment: Então, mas vc ta fazendo query dentro de loop. Melhor separar, fazer uma só de cada, e usar agrupamentos e JOINs. Tente simplificar os passos, esquece o que tá feito até agora e repense em como fazer tudo com menos passos

Comment: Exemplo: em vez de fazer um SELECT pra cada "hash", pode agrupar todos os hashes num array, e fazer um select .... WHERE hash IN ( lista de hashes)  só

Comment: @Bacco blz vou ver se consigo. vou por um fetchall fora da querry e por esse assay no in pra ver se funciona... correto?

Comment: @Bacco assim é 2 busca do mesmo jeito? ex. SELECT * FROM setor WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_setor FROM funcionarios GROUP BY id_setor);

Comment: @Bacco consegui fazer de outra forma... mais funcionou rodou com 5mil querys... pow me ajuda a limpra esse codigo ae como faz com esse IN... pow queria aprender... ou tenho que modular o bd produtos e modificação? qual a melhor opção

Comment: @Bacco eae qual o diagnostico dessa 3ª query?

Answer (score 0):

Como estás a fazer uma query que usa `BETWEEN` numa tabela com muitos registos, o campo que usas no between deve estar configurado como `INDEX`.

O MySQL (e outros motores de base de dados) vão optimizar pesquisas que filtrem por esses campos.

Comment: Index não vai resolver, pois ele não está fazendo between na coluna, e sim numa conversão com STR_TO_DATE. Antes do index ele precisa acertar a coluna para data (vide comentários acima)

Comment: Sim, concordo que o campo tem de ser `date` antes de mais. Mas apesar de ele estar a usar o `STR_TO_DATE`, o campo pode ser `date` já, como não está especificado na pergunta que tipo é, assumo que seja e ai o `INDEX` vai de certeza ajudar.

Comment: @Bacco coloca a tua sugestão de criar campo novo e usar o between sem fazer a conversão como resposta para poder ser votado e aceite. Acho que essa é a solução mais correcta aqui.

Comment: Eu nem postei como resposta ainda pq pode ter outros problemas, só realmente tentei ajudar no que eu vi que claramente está complicado. De qualquer forma, vamos ver se o autor testa e dá um retorno, aí dá para complementar.